# How to fill missing functions to run the codes

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have 13 multiple sheet excel files in one folder to find degree eligibility.

- I read all files using openpyxl.
- Check the missing values.
- Then convert Grade to Grade point value.
- Sort by descending order and remove lower grade duplicates while keeping highest grade.
- Extract Course code last digit as subject credit.
- Then check whether the course code is applicable for GPA or not using credit multiplier.
- Then calculate GPA=(Grade point value*Subject credit*credit multiplier)/Total subject credit.
- The results write in a new sheet in same file.

**My program shows last file last sheet output not all 13 files. What is missing here?**

Program as follows:

```py
dir=os.path.join('file_path')
dir
file_found = False
for files in os.listdir(dir):
    print(f"processing file: '{files}'")
    if files[-4::] == 'xlsx':
        file_found = True
    else:
        print(f"current file does not end with xlsx. Its last 4 chars are: '{files[-4:]}'")
if not file_found:
    print("ERROR: There were no files with ending xlsx")
file_1 = pd.ExcelFile(os.path.join(dir,files),engine='openpyxl')
print('Path of File: ', os.path.join(dir,files))
print('Student: ', pd.read_excel(file_1, sheet_name=0).iloc[0,1])
sheets_names = ['Yr1', 'Yr2', 'Yr3','Subjects']
for names in sheets_names:
    sheet = file_1.sheet_names.index(names)
    print('Sheet: ', file_1.sheet_names[sheet])
    file_original = pd.read_excel(file_1, sheet_name=sheet,engine='openpyxl')
    file_copy = file_original.copy()
    print(file_copy.columns)
for i in range(len(file_copy)):
      file_copy.loc[i,'Grades'] = grades[file_copy.loc[i,'Grade']]
           #sortedby=file_copy.sort_values(file_copy.loc[:,'Course Code'])                               
        # Rows Repeated
dupli = file_copy.loc[file_copy.duplicated(['Course Code'], keep='first')].reset_index()
cont = 0
rows_to_delete = []
for i in range(int(len(dupli))):
           dupli.loc[cont,'Grades'] >= dupli.loc[cont+1,'Grades']:
           rows_to_delete.append(dupli.loc[cont+1,'index'])
            else:
                rows_to_delete.append(dupli.loc[cont,'index'])
                cont += 2
                file_copy.drop(index=rows_to_delete, inplace=True)
                file_copy.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
# subject credit (all last digits of Coruse Code)
file_copy.loc[:,'subject_credits'] = [int(i[-1]) for i in file_copy.loc[:,'Course Code']]
 print('')              file_copy.loc[:,'Credit_Multiplier'] = [str(i[0:4]) for i in file_copy.loc[:,'Course Code']]
credits=[("AMAT",1),("BFIN",1),("DELT",0),("ELEC",1),("MGMT",1),("PHYS",1),("PMAT",1),("COST",1),("MAPS",1),("COSC",1),("STAT",1),("BOTA",1)]              file_copy.loc[:,'course_unit']=file_copy.loc[:,'Credit_Multiplier'].map(dict(credits))               file_copy.loc[:,'subject_credits'].sum()#need to give specific cell
 for index in range(len(file_copy)):
            #total_credits[index] = last digit of Course Code
gpv= file_copy.loc[:,'Grades']*file_copy.loc[:,'subject_credits'] *file_copy.loc[:,'Course_Unit']
                        GPA=gpv/file_copy.loc[:,'subject_credits'].sum()
```

Comment: Hi, I cleaned up your post a little, but can you verify/cleanup the indentation on your code? It will make it easier for people to help debug.

Comment: Since none of this code reads or writes any files nor has anything to do with `openpyxl`, it's not clear what you expect us to do.

Comment: openpyxl used to read all excel files to python. now i add that to start of the program.

Comment: once i run this program it says key error Grade what is mean. by that